# Why isn't this simple Firebase function able to deploy?

Tags: typescript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'd like to create a simple cloud function to add een newly created user to Firestore:

./firebaseConfig.ts :

```
const app = initializeApp({
  ...
});

export const fireStoreDB = getFirestore(app);
```

./functions/index.ts :

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import {DocumentData, DocumentReference, doc, setDoc} from 'firebase/firestore';
import {fireStoreDB} from '../../firebaseConfig';

const createDocumentReferenceHelper = <T = DocumentData>(
    collectionStartingPath: string,
    collectionPath: string[],
) => {
    return doc(
        fireStoreDB,
        collectionStartingPath,
        ...collectionPath,
    ) as DocumentReference<T>;
};

export const newUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
    const docRef = createDocumentReferenceHelper('users', [user.uid]);
    await setDoc(docRef, {email: user.email});
});
```

Upon deploying I get the following error:

```
✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged /Users/<user>/<project>/functions (105.98 KB) for uploading
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function newUser(us-central1)...

Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: 

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
    newUser(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...

Error: There was an error deploying functions
```

I've tried:

- Using the same 'newUser functionality' outside of the Cloud function, which works just fine.
- Replaced newUser function with a http hello world function, which deployed & works without problems.
- Looked into the error logs, but they just repeat the message that the code is wrong.

I expected:

This to be way less of a hassle ;). I believe I'm overthinking it and am missing something very simple.

Any help / push in the right direction will be appreciated!

Comment: I suggest showing the contents of the other log even if you think it's just the same stuff.  The whole point of that other log is to get additional information.  You might also want to share your package.json so we have enough information on how to reproduce this ourselves.

Comment: Hey Doug, thank you for your reply. Reviewing the error logs did indeed help me :).

Comment: If your problem is solved, you can answer your own question here, or you can simply delete the post if you're done with it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, turns out I way overcomplicated things. Reviewing the error logs in the Google Cloud console eventually pointed me to that I wrongly used code from another part of my project:

- Project folder

  - functions(firebase / Google cloud)
  - src
  - firebaseConfig.ts

In the firebaseConfig.ts file I initialise Firebase and Firestore and export it to be used in the src folder:

```
const app = initializeApp({
  ...
});

export const fireStoreDB = getFirestore(app);
```

However [firebase functions run in a trusted environment](https://Okay,%20turns%20out%20I%20way%20overcomplicated%20things.%20Reviewing%20the%20error%20logs%20in%20the%20Google%20Cloud%20console%20eventually%20pointed%20me%20to%20that%20I%20wrongly%20used%20code%20from%20another%20part%20of%20my%20project:%20%20-%20Project%20folder%20%20%20-%20functions(firebase%20/%20Google%20cloud)%20%20%20-%20src%20%20%20-%20firebaseConfig.ts%20%20In%20the%20firebaseConfig.ts%20file%20I%20initialise%20Firebase%20and%20export%20it%20to%20be%20used%20in%20other%20parts%20of%20the%20project.) and therefor need to have the admin sdk enabled and initialised in the index file of the functions folder:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as firebaseAdmin from 'firebase-admin';

firebaseAdmin.initializeApp();
const db = firebaseAdmin.firestore();

export const newUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
    db.doc(`users/${user.uid}`).set({email: user.email});
});
```